# how to configure web browser for a https server running on the same wifi network?

Tags: wireless, server, android, https

I have installed an app on my android device which makes it a `ftp` or `https` server by fixing a `port number` for `listening` and `username` and `password` in case of `ftp server`.

I have successfully tried the `ftp` from `android device` as a `server` and my `ubuntu` `14.10` `desktop` as a `client`(by `filezilla`),both having `local ip's` ,under the same `Wifi` connection.

But when I tried for `https server` on my `android device` by making it to `listen` on `port no.50345` and having `local ip address` of `192.168.1.7` . and started the server.

I switched to my ubuntu desktop in the same home network and changed the `proxy setting` to ip `192.168.1.7` (android device) and port no. to `50345`(port no on which the https server is listening) , and on the address bar I typed

```
https://192.168.1.7:50345
```

but it's not working and showing an error on my android app log file:

```
[jazz]-Listening for connections
[jazz]-192.168.1.10-Error 43:CONNECT method not supported
```

well `192.168.1.10` is my ubuntu system's ip
Can someone tell me why is this so?? It worked well with ftp but not so with https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you set the proxy settings ? If your Android isn't acting as a proxy but as a HTTPS server, you don't need to set any proxy on your desktop, only putting `https://192.168.1.7:50345`in your address bar.

Could you please try it and tell us the answer?

You could also try directly with `curl`on command line, `curl -v https://192.168.1.7:50345`

Comment: thanx @LostInBrittany ,but it didn't worked for me , without proxy setting too it's not working ,and when I tried

Comment: anupam@JAZZ:~$ curl -v https://192.168.1.7:34408
* Rebuilt URL to: https://192.168.1.7:34408/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.1.7...
* connect to 192.168.1.7 port 52950 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 192.168.1.7 port 52950: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.7 port 52950: Connection refused

Comment: If your server is a HTTPS one, you need to specify it in your curl line. Please do `curl -v https://192.168.1.7:50345`  Your `Connection refused` could be normal as you're using HTTP on a HTTPS serve. And why are you doing `curl -v 192.168.1.7:34408` when your server is in port 50345?

Comment: thanx @LostInBritany ,, it worked,,well port no 50345 was just for an example :) ,